# Windows Service OnStop when computer shutdown

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm writing a Windows Service in C#. I want to take the same action for when the service is stopped by the Service control panel as when the system is shutdown. I want to take the same action for either case.

Do I have to override `ServiceBase.OnShutdown()`, or is overriding `ServiceBase.OnStop()` for both cases sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. `OnStop()` gets called when the machine is shutdown. `OnShutdown()` is for when you need to know specifically that the machine is being shutdown.

**UPDATE:**
As has been pointed out in the comments since this was first posted, this is no longer necessarily the case. So your code should be written with the assumption that `OnStop()` may or may not be called when the machine is shut down. If you need to clean up during a shutdown, handle `OnShutdown()`.

Comment: This seems to be no longer true. `OnStop` is **NOT** getting called during machine shutdown

Comment: @Subbu what OS did you notice this? Is this something particular to a .NET version or the OS?

Comment: I can confirm that we don't receive an OnStop call during machine shutdown (AWS EC2 - Windows Server 2012). My recommendation is to implement both (and set CanShutdown to true).

Answer (score 6):

Override `OnShutdown` is the correct method. `OnStop` is not called during shutdown.

Microsoft Windows has added an option called `Fast Startup` which does not actually shutdown the computer.

As noted in the `Fast Startup` setting description, `Restart` isn't affected. This is why the `Restart` triggers `OnShutdown` and `Shutdown` does not.

Turning off `Fast Startup` will trigger `OnShutdown` for both `Restart` and `Shutdown`.

[image: Power Options System Settings]